# TypeError: busboy is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, nodejs, react-native

Buenas Si me podrían este caso que tengo.

Estoy teniendo problemas con busboy

error:

servico.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const Busboy = require('busboy');
    const Arquivo = require('../models/arquivo');
    const Servico = require('../models/servico');
    // try {
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

busboy.on('finish', async () => {

    const { salaoId, servico } = req.body;
    let errors = [];
    let arquivos = [];
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: La pregunta tiene una respuesta sin necesidad de mayor contexto. Aunque las recomendaciones son válidas. Siempre que sea posible añade más información y código relacionado a tu pregunta, o error.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que si tienes instalado busboy, de otro modo instala primero

```
npm install busboy
```

busboy solo exporta una función y por tanto no puedes usar un constructor **new**, solo cambia a:

```
const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
```